# Зачем передавать объект в форму createFormBuilder($task)?

Tags: form, symfony3

Для чего передается объект, например `$task`, при создании формы `createFormBuilder($task)`, если форма обрабатывается и без его него (т.е. не передавая его)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форма берет данные из объекта сущностей `$task` обрабатывает и подставляет их в значения `value`  `<input value='значение'>`.

Comment: Так же верно и то, что: при сабмите формы данные пришедшие в полях формы будут "отражены" в переданном объекте $task (если иное не указано в опциях полей формы).